# "thread 1 recieved signal SIGTRAP, trace/breakpoint trap" , what is this error?

Tags: c

I have an error in my program that when i execute the code stops, i tried debugging it and i had this message **thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, trace/breakpoint trap**
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct s *student;
struct s{
    long long int code;
    char *name;
    short int age;
    float pass_mark;
    bool course;
    struct s *next;
};
student enroll(student head,long long int code1, char *name1,short int age1,bool course1){
    student p,q;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=(student)malloc(sizeof(student));
        head->code=code1;
        head->name=name1;
        head->age=age1;
        head->course=course1;
        head->next=NULL;
        
    }
    else{p=head;
        q=(student)malloc(sizeof(student));
        q->code=code1;
        q->name=name1;
        q->age=age1;
        q->course=course1;
        q->next=p;
        head=q;
    }
    return(head);
}
int main(){
    int x=0,b;
    student head=NULL,q=NULL;
    long long int code1;
    char name1[50];
    short int age;
    bool course1;
    do{
        
        printf("1.register new student. \n");
        printf("0.finish program.\n");
        printf("Enter the number of the task needed: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(x==1){
            
            printf("you chose 1: \n");
            printf("Enter the student code:");
            scanf("%lli",&code1);//code of student
            getchar();
            printf("Enter the student name");
            gets(name1);//name of student
            printf("Enter student age:");
            scanf("%hi",&age);//age of student
            printf("1-Math\n");
            printf("2-computer science");
            printf("\nEnter the number of the course: ");
            scanf("%d",&b);//number of the course
            while((b!=1)&&(b!=2)){
                printf("\nchose 1 or 2: "); 
                scanf("%d",&b);
            }
            if(b==1) course1=1; //math course
            if(b==2) course1=0; //computer science course
            head=enroll(head,code1,name1,age,course1); //fill student info 
            printf("-------------------------------------\n");
        }
}while(x!=0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I used linked lists in this program and the point is to enroll students to a course and there is 2 courses: math or CS, when i enroll a second student an error occured

```
1.register new student.
0.finish program.
Enter the number of the task needed: 1
you chose 1:
Enter the student code:231
Enter the student name Peter
Enter student age:23
1-Math
2-computer science
Enter the number of the course: 1
-------------------------------------
1.register new student.
0.finish program.
Enter the number of the task needed: 1
you chose 1:
Enter the student code:232
Enter the student name Gary
Enter student age:38
1-Math
2-computer science
Enter the number of the course: 2

--------------------------------
Process exited after 39.01 seconds with return value 3221226356
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

so when the first time i entered data there is no problem but in the second time my code stops executing.

Im a beginner so if someone could help me with it and explain it to me in a simple way, i would appreciate it

Update: here is now the program after the changes you recommanded. BTW: i find it difficult to use fgets and dont understand why is gets dangerous it works perfectly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct s student;
struct s{
    long long int code;
    char *name;
    short int age;
    float pass_mark;
    bool course;
    struct s *next;
};
student* enroll(student *head,long long int code1, char name1[50],short int age1,bool course1){
    student *p,*q;
        
        p=head;
        q=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
        q->code=code1;
        strcpy(q->name,name1);
        q->age=age1;
        q->course=course1;
        q->next=p;
        head=q;
        
    return(head);
}
int main(){
    int x=0,b;
    student *head=NULL,*q=NULL;
    long long int code1;
    char name1[50];
    short int age;
    bool course1;
    do{
        
        printf("1.register new student. \n");
        printf("0.finish program.\n");
        printf("Enter the number of the task needed: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(x==1){
            
            printf("you chose 1: \n");
            printf("Enter the student code:");
            scanf("%lli",&code1);//code of student
            getchar();
            printf("Enter the student name: ");
            fgets(name1,50,stdin);//name of student
            printf("%s",name1);
            printf("Enter student age:");
            scanf("%hi",&age);//age of student
            printf("%d",age);
            printf("1-Math\n");
            printf("2-computer science");
            printf("\nEnter the number of the course: ");
            scanf("%d",&b);//number of the course
            while((b!=1)&&(b!=2)){
                printf("\nchoose 1 or 2: "); 
                scanf("%d",&b);
            }
            if(b==1) course1=1; //math course
            if(b==2) course1=0; //computer science course
            head=enroll(head,code1,name1,age,course1); //fill student info 
            printf("%lli",head->code);
            printf("%s",head->name);
            printf("%d",head->age);
            printf("%d",head->course);
            printf("-------------------------------------\n");
        }
}while(x!=0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252890/discussion-on-question-by-henri-thread-1-recieved-signal-sigtrap-trace-breakpo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(student)malloc(sizeof(student));
```

This `malloc` is wrong. `student` is a pointer type, so you allocate enough space to store one pointer, while you need enough space to store one `struct s`.

Do not `typedef` away a pointer. It **will** bite you.

The correct call is

```
(struct s *)malloc(sizeof(struct s))
```

Note how there is only one `*` in the expression.

Comment: There are many other serious problems with the code, but they do not cause crashes immediately.

Comment: Good catch. Once more this shows that typedefing pointer types (like `typedef struct s *student;`) is a very bad idea and only causes confusion. BTW the cast with malloc is useless.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, didnt notice next time i will never typedef a pointer, but still the crash is still there

Comment: @Henri Please use your debugger to gain further insight. Unfortunately this is not a free interactive debugging session.